# Launching a Process Remotely

Tags: c#, process

I am updating a program to be launched using a service called GoAnywhere. The previous version of the program was operated as a scheduled task on a server that had its own copy of a third-party software.

I am calling the process using the following code:

```
ProcessStartInfo pI = new ProcessStartInfo();
pI.CreateNoWindow = true;
/*
* Tried: @\\server\path\to\process, @\\server\c$\path\to\process - generate errors on server
* Tried: @c:\local\path\process, @process - generate errors within GoAnywhere
*/
pI.FileName = @"c:\local\path\process";
pI.Arguments = string.Format("-u {0} -j {1}", "\"User\"", "\"JobName\"");
```

I can run the software on the server directly (mimicking the initial locally scheduled process), but if I launch it via GoAnywhere I get one of two errors.

1. The GoAnywhere task runs my software, which launches the process (@\server\path\to\process). This causes local errors (demonstrated by running the software in the same fashion on the server), including a security error. If the security error is bypassed, then a second error appears indicating that the third-party software is not properly installed. If the errors are not bypassed, then my software times out based on the GoAnywhere task protocol.
2. The GoAnywhere task runs my software, which launches the process (@c:\local\path\process). However, the process fails with the following caught exception.

   ```
   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at InsightCass.Program.Main(String[] args)
   ```

It is clear that using the local path allows me to run it directly on the server, but not via the remote task. Is there a way to indicate the server process using its full server path, but have the server treat it like it was being called locally?

Comment: Where is the "GoAnywhere" task running from?

Comment: It is a different server from the one where my software is supposed to run.